# Object making everything else in viewport transparent

Tags: 3d-view, transparency

I have an object that makes everything else transparent in viewport. Here's what it should look like:

[image]

And here's what it looks like in solid mode:

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: In the Object panel > Viewport Display, maybe you've enabled the In Front option?

Comment: I don't remember ever touching it, but you're right, it was enabled. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Go into the *Object panel > Viewport Display*, disable the *In Front* option.